# Ошибка subprocess.check_output: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte"

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

Когда я использую:

```
subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True).decode('utf-8')
```

то получаю эту ошибку:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Вот вывод `print(subprocess.check_output('dir', shell=True))`:

```py
b' \x92\xae\xac \xa2 \xe3\xe1\xe2\xe0\xae\xa9\xe1\xe2\xa2\xa5 C \xad\xa5 \xa8\xac\xa5\xa5\xe2 \xac\xa5\xe2\xaa\xa8.\r\n \x91\xa5\xe0\xa8\xa9\xad\xeb\xa9 \xad\xae\xac\xa5\xe0 \xe2\xae\xac\xa0: 3858-A3CB\r\n\r\n \x91\xae\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa6\xa8\xac\xae\xa5 \xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8 C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\soft_and_code\\ph-dl\\kivy\\shareit\\filesharerkivy\\filesharekivy v1.3\\project\\optimazer 1\r\n\r\n27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          .\r\n27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          ..\r\n27.08.2020  15:27             1\xff157 cursor_info.py\r\n27.08.2020  10:41           713\xff820 output.mkv\r\n27.08.2020  10:42           715\xff370 output.mp4\r\n26.08.2020  19:54            15\xff480 passwordicon.py\r\n27.08.2020  10:38    <DIR>          recordings\r\n21.08.2020  13:32             3\xff713 recording_app.zip\r\n26.08.2020  19:54               710 video_encoder.py\r\n               6 \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xa2      1\xff450\xff250 \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2\r\n               3 \xaf\xa0\xaf\xae\xaa  600\xff902\xff475\xff776 \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2 \xe1\xa2\xae\xa1\xae\xa4\xad\xae\r\n'
```

Как мне получить результат выполнения системной команды в нормальном (в utf-8) виде?

---

PS OS Windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Команды оболочки в русских версиях Windows выводят результат в кодировке cp866:

```
x = b' \x92\xae\xac \xa2 \xe3\xe1\xe2\xe0\xae\xa9\xe1\xe2\xa2\xa5 C \xad\xa5 \xa8\xac\xa5\xa5\xe2 \xac\xa5\xe2\xaa\xa8.\r\n \x91\xa5\xe0\xa8\xa9\xad\xeb\xa9 \xad\xae\xac\xa5\xe0 \xe2\xae\xac\xa0: 3858-A3CB\r\n\r\n \x91\xae\xa4\xa5\xe0\xa6\xa8\xac\xae\xa5 \xaf\xa0\xaf\xaa\xa8 C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\soft_and_code\\ph-dl\\kivy\\shareit\\filesharerkivy\\filesharekivy v1.3\\project\\optimazer 1\r\n\r\n27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          .\r\n27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          ..\r\n27.08.2020  15:27             1\xff157 cursor_info.py\r\n27.08.2020  10:41           713\xff820 output.mkv\r\n27.08.2020  10:42           715\xff370 output.mp4\r\n26.08.2020  19:54            15\xff480 passwordicon.py\r\n27.08.2020  10:38    <DIR>          recordings\r\n21.08.2020  13:32             3\xff713 recording_app.zip\r\n26.08.2020  19:54               710 video_encoder.py\r\n               6 \xe4\xa0\xa9\xab\xae\xa2      1\xff450\xff250 \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2\r\n               3 \xaf\xa0\xaf\xae\xaa  600\xff902\xff475\xff776 \xa1\xa0\xa9\xe2 \xe1\xa2\xae\xa1\xae\xa4\xad\xae\r\n'
 
print(x.decode('cp866'))
```

Результат:

```
 Том в устройстве C не имеет метки.
 Серийный номер тома: 3858-A3CB

 Содержимое папки C:\Users\User\Desktop\soft_and_code\ph-dl\kivy\shareit\filesharerkivy\filesharekivy v1.3\ingproject\optimazer 1

27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          .
27.08.2020  15:27    <DIR>          ..
27.08.2020  15:27             1 157 cursor_info.py
27.08.2020  10:41           713 820 output.mkv
27.08.2020  10:42           715 370 output.mp4
26.08.2020  19:54            15 480 passwordicon.py
27.08.2020  10:38    <DIR>          recordings
21.08.2020  13:32             3 713 recording_app.zip
26.08.2020  19:54               710 video_encoder.py
               6 файлов      1 450 250 байт
               3 папок  600 902 475 776 байт свободно
```